# Prove that if $a+b-c=1$ then $a^2+b^2-c^2=1-2ab+2c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a+b-c=1$ then prove that $$a^2+b^2-c^2=1-2ab+2c$$

Comment: *Hint* : $a+b = 1+c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since$$a+b=1+c$$
Squaring both sides gives 
$$a^2+b^2+2ab=1+c^2+2c$$

Subtracting $2ab$ and $c^2$ from both sides gives required equation id est..

$$a^2+b^2-c^2=1-2ab+2c$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
a^2+b^2-c^2 & =  (a+b)^2 - 2ab - c^2 \\
& =  (1+c)^2 - 2ab - c^2 \\
& = 1 - 2ab + 2c
\end{align}

where the transition from the second to the third expression derives from the condition $a+b-c=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a+b-c=1$, $a+b=c+1$ so that

$$\begin{align}
(a+b)^2&=a^2+2ab+b^2 \\
&=(c+1)^2 \\
&=c^2+2c+1.
\end{align}$$ Thus $a^2+b^2-c^2=2c-2ab+1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a+b-c=1$, then:

$$(a+b-c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab-bc-ca)=1$$
$$a^2+b^2-c^2=1+2(-ab+bc+ca-c^2)$$
$$a^2+b^2-c^2=1-2ab+c(a+b-c)$$
$$a^2+b^2-c^2=1-2ab+c$$